# Удалить часть строки после заданной подстроки

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

Есть строка,посередине есть `</br>`

подскажите как мне удалить  `</br>` и все что идет после него до конца строки?

Comment: На всякий случай: HTML лучше не парсить регулярными выражениями. В данном случае может и сойдет, но вообще он слишком хаотичен для регулярок.

Comment: Откуда кстати у вас в строке `</br>`? в HTML такого встречаться не должно, этот тег используется как просто `<br>` без закрывающего.

Comment: @Nickolay по стандарту HTML5 одиночные теги тоже закрываются. Вот только закрываются они в конце: `<br/><img src="#"/><hr/>`. А вот приведённую выше ерунду кривые WYSIWYG-редакторы CMS генерируют.

Comment: @Дмитрий (за мысль про кривые wysiwyg спасибо!) Небольшой офтоп, если кому-то интересно: ваш комментарий можно понять по разному, а на английском SO есть развернутые ответы по тому, что [HTML5 говорит на эту тему](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1946426/html-5-is-it-br-br-or-br). В HTML5 для совместимости разрешены оба варианта `<br>`, `<br/>`, но лишний слеш не является чем-то обязательным или рекомендуемым.

Answer (score 3):

можно так

```
$result = strstr($str, '</br>', true);
```

Comment: Еще можно `$result = array_shift(explode('</br>', $str));`