# Удалить с конца строки все до определенного символа через регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Ребята, подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить с конца строки все до определенного символа через регулярное выражение.

Пример -
"Мягкая мебель{csvnc}Диваны прямые{csvnc}Диван Алтай (Марселль Шампайн-1)"

Надо удалить "{csvnc}Диван Алтай (Марселль Шампайн-1)" или просто "Диван Алтай (Марселль Шампайн-1)"

Comment: дубликаты: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/446010/178576), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/502573/178576) и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Это не совсем то, к сожалению. Надо именно через регулярное выражение.
Плюс разделитель категорий {csvnc} может встречаться несколько раз

Comment: так подберите себе то, что, подходит под ваше определение термина «регулярное выражение»: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=[регулярные-выражения]+последнее

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, благодаря жадному поведению регулярных выражений, можно так:

Найти: `^(.+)\{csvnc\}.+$`

Заменить: `$1`

Comment: А если Диван Алтай не будет последним? Но это у автора нужно уточнять, может ли такое быть.

Comment: Я так понял, что нужно просто удалить последнее поле вместе с разделителем или без него. Но если ошибся, конечно, пусть автор уточнит.

Comment: Да, То, что надо! Огромное спасибо.
Да, нужно просто удалить последнее поле вместе с разделителем или без него. Все правильно.